# How To Open a Video in a New Window

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a landing page for a course with chapters and videos. Videos are showed like a list (http://cursos7.com.br/landing_dev.php?curso=10), a  and

construction with links.

How can click a link of the list and make it open the video in a new window, with the same size of the video it's playing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a reference to a JS plugin called Titan Lightbox in your code.
Haven't used it before, but if you already decided on using this one, and paid for it, you might as well use it for the videos as well?

Check out examples here:
http://codecanyon.net/item/titan-lightbox-for-wordpress/full_screen_preview/3158242

```
<a href="URL" data-titan-ligthbox="on">Video name here</a>
```

If you do not use this plugin, I would advice you to find a lightbox alternative:
http://codegeekz.com/best-jquery-lightbox-plugins-for-developers/

The "new" window can also be achieved with javascript `window.open():`

```
<a onclick="window.open(URL, '_blank', 'location=yes,height=500,width=600,scrollbars=no,status=yes');">Video</a>
```

Comment: Jafu thank you very much! Your are right about the Titan, but i´m going with your window.open tip.